# How to ignore a custom header in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to find a creative way to get the dataframe of several sheets within a spreadsheet that's quite irregular but I can't find the way to do it.

If I try this:

```
file= 'filename.xlsx'
df = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
print(df)
```

This is my current output:

```
        A          |     B     |    C
1    Random text   | Empty cell|Empty cell
    ------------------------------------
2    Empty cell    |           |
    ------------------------------------
3    Empty cell    |           |
    ------------------------------------  
4    CODE          |HEADER 2   | HEADER 3
    ------------------------------------    
5    INFORMATION   |INFORMATION|INFORMATION
```

I want to start my dataframe in the CODE row and column, but pandas just gets the "Random text" cell as the first cell

This is my desired output:

```
4    CODE          |HEADER 2   | HEADER 3
    ------------------------------------    
5    INFORMATION   |INFORMATION|INFORMATION
```

How would you make Pandas ignore the first rows? It has to be value-based because in the next sheets CODE starts in row 8, and in the next one in row 3

Comment: `import pandas as pd`, `df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', header=3`

Comment: @Erfan Thanks for the answer, but as I said in the question, the first-cell referencing has to be value-based because "CODE" in the next sheet starts in row 5, in the next one in another one, and since I don't have control over the supplier's excel and they can modify it without telling me, I want to make sure I can avoid this risk by referencing it dinamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about XLRD, but Pandas has an easy way in the excel reading method that allows you to specify which row is your headers. That would be an easy fix unless you're intent on using XLRD.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know that I could input the rows to ignore manually by skipping rows, but as I said in the question, the first-cell referencing has to be value-based because "CODE" in the next sheet starts in row 5, in the next one in another one, and since I don't have control over the supplier's excel and they can modify it without telling me, I want to make sure I can avoid this risk by referencing it dinamically

Comment: Ah ok I understand now. I've done something similar, and my solution was basically to return through the rows and columns of a sheet using XLRD to find the string I was looking for and then return that. My sheets weren't so large that it might cause an issue, but I don't know about the sheets you are dealing with. Also, if 'CODE' is near the top it may not be a runtime issue no matter the size.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd

file= 'filename.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(open(file, 'rb'),sheet_name='sheetname', skiprows=[0,1,2])
```

Alternatively you can use header argument as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I said in the question, the first-cell referencing has to be value-based because "CODE" in the next sheet starts in row 5, in the next one in another one, and since I don't have control over the supplier's excel and they can modify it without telling me, I want to make sure I can avoid this risk by referencing it dinamically

Comment: Alright I will add an alternative approach for dynamic parsing then.

Answer (score 1):

In my previous answer I pointed a static solution, and in this one I have added a helper function for dynamic parsing. `get_header_index` helper function dynamically gets the index of the row containing header keyword in the first column. You may change the `col_index` argument if you believe header keyword is in another column tough. Likewise you can change keyword argument's input as you like. The output `dfs` is dictionary of dataframes where keys are sheet names of a given workbook.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_header_index(sheet, col_index=0, keyword='code'):
    arr = sheet[sheet.columns[int(col_index)]]
    header_index = arr[arr.str.contains(str(keyword), na=False)].iloc[[0,]].index[0]
    return header_index

file = 'filename.xlsx'
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(open(file, 'rb'), sheet_name=None)

dfs = {}
for name, sheet in sheets_dict.items():
    header = get_header_index(sheet, col_index=0, keyword='code') + 1
    df = pd.read_excel(open(file, 'rb'), sheet_name=name, header=header)
    dfs[name] = df
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply, but I got this 2 errors and I cannot tell where's the mistake:

IndexError: cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError  Traceback (most recent call last)
     12 for name, sheet in sheets_dict.items():
---> 13     header = get_header_index(sheet, col_index=0, keyword='Code') + 1
     14     df = pd.read_excel(open(file, 'rb'), sheet_name=name, header=header)
     15     dfs[name] = df

IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

Comment: Hey @Gonzalo, this is likely because not all your sheets share the same keyword. You may add an IndexError exception to the for loop so that it won't give you same error. Alternatively you may construct a get_header_index function that receives a list of keywords instead of a single keyword string. These options depend on your situation. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a form of what I did in mine, adjusted for your use (based on my previous comment):

```
for file in file_names:  # Iterate through all of the individual report files
        book = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
        sheetname = get_sheetname(book)
        if sheetname is not None:  # Check that sheet name is valid
            sheet = book.sheet_by_name(sheetname)
            nrows = sheet.nrows
            ncols = sheet.ncols
            for i in range(nrows):
                for j in range(ncols):
                    check = sheet.cell_value(i, j) 
                    if check.contains("CODE"):
                        return (i, j)
```